# How get image urls form RSS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rss, rss-reader

I have been trying to parse image URLs from various news RSS URLs like

https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml

I am using **rss-parser** library for this purpose but the documentation and examples have every other item other than media content and images. Is there a proper way for parsing images from all kind of rss urls of news channels.? My attempt is given below.

```
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
const parser = new Parser({
    customFields: {
        feed: ['author'],
        item: ['categories', 'author'],
    }
});


rssUrlParser: async (url,url_id="",department_id="") => {
        try {
            const result = await parser.parseURL(url);
 const feed = {
                "title": result.title || "",
                "link": result.link || "",
                "author": result.author || "",
                "description": result.description || "",
                "image": (result.image && result.url) || "",
                "url_id": url_id,
                "department_id":department_id
            }; 
            const items = result.items.length ? result.items.map(i => {


                i.author = i.author || "";
                i.image = i.enclosure ? i.enclosure.url : "";
                i.categories = i.categories || [];
                i.enclosure = i.enclosure || {};
                return i;
            }) : [];

            return {
                feed,
                items
            };
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. `so.xml` is just the xml content i got from your url above.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const { transform } = require('camaro')

;(async function () {
    const xml = fs.readFileSync('so.xml', 'utf-8')
    const template = {
        images: ['//media:content[@medium="image"]', '@url']
    }

    const result = await transform(xml, template)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

})()
```

output

```
{
    "images": [
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/world/16yemen2-promo/16yemen2-promo-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/16dc-prexy/16dc-prexy-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/business/16UAW1/16UAW1-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/06/19/science/19xp-hair/19xp-hair-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/00Dems-Age-promo/00Dems-Age-01-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/16dc-trump1/16dc-trump1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/16warren-rally-new1/16warren-rally-new1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/16dc-coons1-promo/16dc-coons1-promo-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/pageoneplus/17readers-kavanaugh/17readers-kavanaugh-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/15dc-marja1/00dc-marjah1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/world/17usbriefing_amcore/17usbriefing_israel_elections-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/15/nyregion/17nytoday-1/13giuliani-sub1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/09/us/politics/16daily1/16daily1-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/business/16db-newsletter-saudi/merlin_160850271_c07da32b-53d5-4cec-9c29-1887c4f262c8-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/opinion/16Landau1/merlin_160480368_10a849bf-724c-4da6-a5d4-0a3d84d9e5ac-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/opinion/17shehadeh3/17shehadeh3-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/opinion/16saudiarabia/16saudiarabia-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/opinion/16warzel-illo/16warzel-illo-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/opinion/16krugmanWeb/16krugmanWeb-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/opinion/16Bacevich1/16Bacevich1-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/opinion/16rallyWeb/16rallyWeb-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/12/opinion/12sainato/12sainato-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/15/opinion/15Leonhardt/merlin_160698273_634a6005-f3ef-44aa-8ccd-c066ae269432-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/15/opinion/15Blow/15Blow-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/11/multimedia/11xp-skate6/11xp-skate6-moth-v3.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/us/politics/16dc-judiciary/16dc-judiciary-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/books/17Chrisrock/17Chrisrock-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/sports/16russia1/merlin_147710904_598b80f7-f69a-48ce-be03-3a3d3f212269-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/realestate/17trump-jamaica1/merlin_126207707_09d87e42-6d3a-4946-9797-1026ac691fe4-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/15/us/politics/15dc-guantanamo1/15dc-guantanamo1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/science/00ILSI4/00ILSI4-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/science/16PURDUE1/16PURDUE1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/world/16Brexit-sub/16Brexit-sub-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/09/smarter-living/00wc-flossing/00wc-flossing-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/smarter-living/16sl-phonelife/00sl-phonelife-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/08/12/smarter-living/12sl-wrongthing/16sl-wrongthing-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/12/magazine/12atwar-stargazing-2/12atwar-stargazing-2-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/books/17bookbarry1/17bookbarry1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/10/arts/10lopez-answers1/merlin_160385682_2ceafcda-79e1-44c0-bc0b-b3d6a426faf9-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/11/dining/06Kitchen-stew1/06Kitchen-stew1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/11/science/11GERMS-NURSINGHOMES1/merlin_160631244_6b1bdb0c-11fe-496d-8c3b-0e243ac1c889-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/10/science/10LASKER1/10LASKER1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/17/science/10SCI-MATTER-SKULLS1/10SCI-MATTER-SKULLS1-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/travel/16italy-transumanza1/16italy-transumanza1-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/10/t-magazine/10tmag-pepper-slide-5DNI-copy/10tmag-pepper-slide-5DNI-copy-moth-v2.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/t-magazine/16tmag-romanandwilliams/16tmag-romanandwilliams-moth.jpg",
        "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2019/09/16/sports/16nfl-learned-top/16nfl-learned-top-moth-v2.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your method is perfect but I solved by making below-mentioned changes
const parser = new Parser({
    customFields: {
        feed: ['author'],
        // item: ,
        item:[
            ['categories', 'author'],
            ['media:content', 'media']
        ]
    }
});
Now the url can be parser by media["$"].url from a loop. But other issue notitced is that some of the rss urls are having different structure for images. For example below mentioned url has the images of the news inside enclosure tag.

https://www.boston.com/tag/local-news/feed

Comment: @UJIndia not sure i understand what other problem is :-/